# Android ambient shadow weakens as background color darkens?

Tags: android, material-design, shadow, elevation

So, I have an an AppCompatButton with the following style:

```
<style name="InputButton">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/blur_state_list</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_sans_semibold</item>
<item name="android:outlineAmbientShadowColor">?colorAmbient</item>
<item name="android:outlineSpotShadowColor">?colorAmbient</item>
<item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
<item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/spacing_large_4</item>
<item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/spacing_large_4</item>
<item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/spacing_13dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/spacing_13dp</item>
<item name="android:minHeight">0dp</item>
<item name="android:elevation">6dp</item>
```

The background drawable is done this way

```
<item android:id="@android:id/mask">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="?colorFragmentBackground" />
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/input_spacing" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <selector>
        <item android:state_enabled="false">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="?colorTextSecondary1" />
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/input_spacing" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/input_spacing" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
</item>
```

Surrounded by ripple tag. SO won't let me post the ripple tag...

When the background color is bright. (white, yellow, etc...), it casts a strong shadow:
[image]

But when the background color darkens, the shadow weakens significantly:

[image]

Is there a setting somewhere, an attr I can use to maintain shadow strength regardless of background color? I have tried spotShadowAlpha and ambientShadowAlpha to no avail.

Comment: See the [checker shadow illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checker_shadow_illusion) for a similar optical illusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the effect of the perception of colors by human vision.

In fact the shadow is the same.

Answer (score 1):

As Ruslan has commented, it seems that is just an optic ilusion. Here are the images side by side:

[image]